# Powershell commands in C# won't work

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10

I have a C# WPF application running on Windows 10 from which I call Powershell commands. Typically, the code runs successfully and everything's fine, but now it does not.

The Powershell commands run without any error, but do not do anything. I have not changed any of the code pertaining to these commands.

The method I call is below:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) //Mounts iso image
{
       ps.AddScript("Mount-DiskImage");
       ps.AddParameter("ImagePath", IMG);
       string outp = "";
       Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();
       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           foreach (PSObject invoke in PSOutput)
               sw.WriteLine(invoke.ToString());
           outp = sw.ToString();
       }
       if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
       {
           outp += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("{0} errors: ", ps.Streams.Error.Count);
           foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error)
                    outp += Environment.NewLine + err.ToString();
           MessageBox.Show(outp);
       }
 }
```

Edit: Changed code to return error if one is raised. No error was shown when testing.

Edit 2: Added additional error check. This returns an error, but I can't tell what it is.

Edit 3: Changed code to see error output and it said I failed to provide the `ImagePath`parameter (which I did not). I checked the `IMG` parameter before I passed it to the method, and it is indeed a full path. What's wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Make sure your `IMG` parameter is valid.

Comment: @Icemanid Pretty sure that parameter hasn't changed either. It should be a valid global path to an image.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/ Scroll down to "Synchronous execution". There is how to grab error output (if any).

Comment: After edit: Did you also check Error-Stream `if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)` ?

Comment: have you tried running as admin?

Comment: @derloopkat I have been the entire time (in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, fixed my own problem (for now at least). For one thing, when I was originally trying different things out to fix it, I changed the line `ps.AddCommand()` to `ps.AddScript()` and forgot to change it back when it didn't work. `ps.AddCommand()` is obviously the correct method to call for this scenario. This (in and of itself) did not fix my problem. [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2013544/error-message-when-you-manage-a-vhd-file-in-windows-server-2008-a-virt) I found the solution for a similar problem, so I tried it on mine and it worked.

To summarize, navigate to `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\FsDepends` in the registry. Click on the DWORD value `Start` and change it from `3` to `0`. Restart to apply. Apparently it has something to do with messed up timings in that particular Windows service. I'm not sure if this is a permanent solution, but all my code seems to be in order now, so we'll see.

Comment: @Fildor Completed.